Ninja Trader 8 - Rob Booker Intraday Pivots Calculation
I have just converted the CTrader version of the Rob Booker Intraday Pivot to NT8.
The code for the NT8 version of this indicator is attached to this message.
For some reason, the calculation of the actual pivots is different.
Any ideas?
This is the NT8 version: enter image description here
This is the Trading view version: enter image description here
Actual NT8 code:
#region Using declarations
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using NinjaTrader.Cbi;
using NinjaTrader.Gui;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.Chart;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.SuperDom;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.Tools;
using NinjaTrader.Data;
using NinjaTrader.NinjaScript;
using NinjaTrader.Core.FloatingPoint;

#endregion



#region NinjaScript generated code. Neither change nor remove.

namespace NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Indicators
{
    public partial class Indicator : NinjaTrader.Gui.NinjaScript.IndicatorRenderBase
    {
        
        private RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[] cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints;

        
        public RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(BarsPeriodType shortTermTimeFrame, int shortTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush shortTermColor, int shortTermThickness, DashStyleHelper shortTermStyle, BarsPeriodType mediumTermTimeFrame, int mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush mediumTermColor, int mediumTermThickness, DashStyleHelper mediumTermStyle, BarsPeriodType longTermTimeFrame, int longTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush longTermColor, int longTermThickness, DashStyleHelper longTermStyle)
        {
            return RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(Input, shortTermTimeFrame, shortTermTimeFramePeriod, shortTermColor, shortTermThickness, shortTermStyle, mediumTermTimeFrame, mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, mediumTermColor, mediumTermThickness, mediumTermStyle, longTermTimeFrame, longTermTimeFramePeriod, longTermColor, longTermThickness, longTermStyle);
        }


        
        public RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(ISeries<double> input, BarsPeriodType shortTermTimeFrame, int shortTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush shortTermColor, int shortTermThickness, DashStyleHelper shortTermStyle, BarsPeriodType mediumTermTimeFrame, int mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush mediumTermColor, int mediumTermThickness, DashStyleHelper mediumTermStyle, BarsPeriodType longTermTimeFrame, int longTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush longTermColor, int longTermThickness, DashStyleHelper longTermStyle)
        {
            if (cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints != null)
                for (int idx = 0; idx < cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints.Length; idx++)
                    if (cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].ShortTermTimeFrame == shortTermTimeFrame && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].ShortTermTimeFramePeriod == shortTermTimeFramePeriod && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].ShortTermColor == shortTermColor && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].ShortTermThickness == shortTermThickness && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].ShortTermStyle == shortTermStyle && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].MediumTermTimeFrame == mediumTermTimeFrame && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].MediumTermTimeFramePeriod == mediumTermTimeFramePeriod && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].MediumTermColor == mediumTermColor && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].MediumTermThickness == mediumTermThickness && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].MediumTermStyle == mediumTermStyle && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].LongTermTimeFrame == longTermTimeFrame && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].LongTermTimeFramePeriod == longTermTimeFramePeriod && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].LongTermColor == longTermColor && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].LongTermThickness == longTermThickness && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].LongTermStyle == longTermStyle && cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx].EqualsInput(input))
                        return cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints[idx];
            return CacheIndicator<RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints>(new RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(){ ShortTermTimeFrame = shortTermTimeFrame, ShortTermTimeFramePeriod = shortTermTimeFramePeriod, ShortTermColor = shortTermColor, ShortTermThickness = shortTermThickness, ShortTermStyle = shortTermStyle, MediumTermTimeFrame = mediumTermTimeFrame, MediumTermTimeFramePeriod = mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, MediumTermColor = mediumTermColor, MediumTermThickness = mediumTermThickness, MediumTermStyle = mediumTermStyle, LongTermTimeFrame = longTermTimeFrame, LongTermTimeFramePeriod = longTermTimeFramePeriod, LongTermColor = longTermColor, LongTermThickness = longTermThickness, LongTermStyle = longTermStyle }, input, ref cacheRobBookerIntradayPivotPoints);
        }

    }
}

namespace NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.MarketAnalyzerColumns
{
    public partial class MarketAnalyzerColumn : MarketAnalyzerColumnBase
    {
        
        public Indicators.RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(BarsPeriodType shortTermTimeFrame, int shortTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush shortTermColor, int shortTermThickness, DashStyleHelper shortTermStyle, BarsPeriodType mediumTermTimeFrame, int mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush mediumTermColor, int mediumTermThickness, DashStyleHelper mediumTermStyle, BarsPeriodType longTermTimeFrame, int longTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush longTermColor, int longTermThickness, DashStyleHelper longTermStyle)
        {
            return indicator.RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(Input, shortTermTimeFrame, shortTermTimeFramePeriod, shortTermColor, shortTermThickness, shortTermStyle, mediumTermTimeFrame, mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, mediumTermColor, mediumTermThickness, mediumTermStyle, longTermTimeFrame, longTermTimeFramePeriod, longTermColor, longTermThickness, longTermStyle);
        }


        
        public Indicators.RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(ISeries<double> input , BarsPeriodType shortTermTimeFrame, int shortTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush shortTermColor, int shortTermThickness, DashStyleHelper shortTermStyle, BarsPeriodType mediumTermTimeFrame, int mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush mediumTermColor, int mediumTermThickness, DashStyleHelper mediumTermStyle, BarsPeriodType longTermTimeFrame, int longTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush longTermColor, int longTermThickness, DashStyleHelper longTermStyle)
        {
            return indicator.RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(input, shortTermTimeFrame, shortTermTimeFramePeriod, shortTermColor, shortTermThickness, shortTermStyle, mediumTermTimeFrame, mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, mediumTermColor, mediumTermThickness, mediumTermStyle, longTermTimeFrame, longTermTimeFramePeriod, longTermColor, longTermThickness, longTermStyle);
        }
    
    }
}

namespace NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Strategies
{
    public partial class Strategy : NinjaTrader.Gui.NinjaScript.StrategyRenderBase
    {
        
        public Indicators.RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(BarsPeriodType shortTermTimeFrame, int shortTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush shortTermColor, int shortTermThickness, DashStyleHelper shortTermStyle, BarsPeriodType mediumTermTimeFrame, int mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush mediumTermColor, int mediumTermThickness, DashStyleHelper mediumTermStyle, BarsPeriodType longTermTimeFrame, int longTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush longTermColor, int longTermThickness, DashStyleHelper longTermStyle)
        {
            return indicator.RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(Input, shortTermTimeFrame, shortTermTimeFramePeriod, shortTermColor, shortTermThickness, shortTermStyle, mediumTermTimeFrame, mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, mediumTermColor, mediumTermThickness, mediumTermStyle, longTermTimeFrame, longTermTimeFramePeriod, longTermColor, longTermThickness, longTermStyle);
        }


        
        public Indicators.RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(ISeries<double> input , BarsPeriodType shortTermTimeFrame, int shortTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush shortTermColor, int shortTermThickness, DashStyleHelper shortTermStyle, BarsPeriodType mediumTermTimeFrame, int mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush mediumTermColor, int mediumTermThickness, DashStyleHelper mediumTermStyle, BarsPeriodType longTermTimeFrame, int longTermTimeFramePeriod, Brush longTermColor, int longTermThickness, DashStyleHelper longTermStyle)
        {
            return indicator.RobBookerIntradayPivotPoints(input, shortTermTimeFrame, shortTermTimeFramePeriod, shortTermColor, shortTermThickness, shortTermStyle, mediumTermTimeFrame, mediumTermTimeFramePeriod, mediumTermColor, mediumTermThickness, mediumTermStyle, longTermTimeFrame, longTermTimeFramePeriod, longTermColor, longTermThickness, longTermStyle);
        }

    }
}

#endregion

I have tried changing the time zone for NT8 to the Trading View equivalent but that didn't work.
